# How to end a for loop after a given amount of time

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, timeit

I execute my code in a loop for many objects and it seems that process too much time.

I would like to add a condition that stops the execution after 30 min for example. How should it be done? Do I need another for loop and the `timeit` module for that or it can be done easier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with something like this:

```
import time

time_limit = 60 * 30 # Number of seconds in one minute
t0 = time.time()
for obj in list_of_objects_to_iterate_over:
    do_some_stuff(obj)   
    if time.time() - t0 > time_limit:
        break
```

The `break` statement will exit the loop whenever the end of your iteration is reached after the time limit you have set.

Answer (score 1):

You could Implement a starting time and stop executing after 30 mins past from starting time

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
starting_time = datetime.now()
for item in something:
    #do something
    if (datetime.now()- starting_time) //timedelta(minutes=1) >= 30:
        break
```

Comment: Want to add a comment, that this code is not optimal for a quick operations inside your iterations, since on each iteration you are going to check the time, but i guess that's the way to go in your case

Answer (score 0):

So here is my variant how this can be done(assuming that we gather data via sql response):

```
  for i in items:
    if total_records % 100 == 0:
        logger.warning(
            "Processed {} items in {} ms".format(total_records, int(time.time() * 1000) - start_time_ms))
    if int(time.time() * 1000) - start_time_ms > 3600000:
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
        return total_records
```